# Adding multiple files to a tablespace

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

In Oracle, we have huge amount of data imported daily, which requires us to create data files off and on in a tablespace.

Wonder if we create two data files simultaneously, will it use both when one is full? Or it will use only latest one?

Comment: Why tablespace? You can create data files..

Comment: Yeah, I mean data files. Does it uses only latest one?

Comment: What does *"two tablespace (data files)"* mean? A tablespace can have any number of files. You can add files to a tablespace or set it to auto-extend. You don't add a tablespace to increase space for new data.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithms used to allocate space in different datafiles in a single tablespace are not documented except in [the database administration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/logical.htm#GUID-C205981E-182A-466D-B151-090455F9ECE7__BABFIFCF)
where it just says:

> the database can allocate extents for a segment in any data file in
> the tablespace

It can change between two releases but it is likely based on same round robin algorithm.

Here is a short demo with Oracle 19 which shows that some round robin algorithm is used:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum=1;

BANNER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> create tablespace test;

Tablespace created.

SQL> alter tablespace test add datafile;

Tablespace altered.

SQL> alter tablespace test add datafile;

Tablespace altered.

SQL> select tablespace_name, file_id, file_name from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='TEST';

TABLESPACE_NAME     FILE_ID FILE_NAME
-------------------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
TEST                120 /u02/oradata/CDB2/datafile/o1_mf_test_hhxspzt3_.dbf
TEST                121 /u02/oradata/CDB2/datafile/o1_mf_test_hhxsq112_.dbf
TEST                122 /u02/oradata/CDB2/datafile/o1_mf_test_hhxsq2kt_.dbf

SQL> --
SQL> create table t tablespace test as select * from dba_objects ;

Table created.

SQL> select distinct file_id
  2  from dba_extents
  3  where segment_name='T'
  4  and   segment_type='TABLE'
  5  and tablespace_name='TEST';

   FILE_ID
----------
       121
       120
       122
```